# How do you harass early game as Warlock

Tags: dota-2, dota

I often read that Warlock is a good early babysitter and harasser. Can anyone explain how to build and play a Warlock in early game to harass an enemy carry such as Anti-Mage ?

What skills/items should I take early on ?

Comment: fatal bonds and shadow word are your primary means of early game harass

Comment: I was looking a practical solution, telling me in what order I should get my skills and when I should use my skills and also what I should buy

Comment: http://www.dota2alttab.com/#Warlock says it all. Consider maxing heal first in a support role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the most important to max out the `fatal bonds`. This spell is very important since it will deal damage to the hero even if he's not in range. You should not forget about the other damaging spells and you very powerful ultimate.

To babysit properly you should sit in front of the battling creeps so that your carry can farm with no worries and you harass the enemy hero. 
Take note that when you attack the enemy hero, you get aggro from his creeps. You can lose quickly aggro by attacking your own creeps using `Ctrl + A + click` on friendly creep. This will make you lose aggro (even from enemy towers!). This way you harass the enemy and make the enemy creeps lose momentum by switching targets very often.

Your carry (supposing you babysit a carry,, otherwise it's pretty pointless) should only last hit the enemy creeps because you don't want to push the lane too much so that you stay in the safe area.

Regarding items, you should put `observer wards` the near forest (if Radiant bottom or if Dire top) you should go for `Arcane Boots` and `Mekansm` or `Pipe of insight`. These are items that are quite cheap and they are of course sometimes situational, but usually they come in handy when playing a true support.
A very important item for the warlock though is the `Refresher Orb` since it doubles your ultimate and `Aghanim's Scepter` that makes your ultimate spawn 2 infernal golems.
You could also use `Rod of Atos` a very powerful item that is underused. It cripples the enemy hero slowing him a lot and it has a pretty huge range.

Comment: nooooooo, refresher and scepter should almost never be purchased by a warlock unless they're seriously stomping and has so much gold he doesn't know what to do with it

Comment: I was laning with a Void who told me to stop spamming fatal bonds. Was he mistaken ? Fatal bonds is very expensive mana wise. Since you have to buy courier + wards in pubs do I have to buy 2 mana pots ? That would leave me no gold for branches

Comment: @BlueTrin There's a chance it was pushing the lane too much if it was binding a bunch of creeps together and causing them to take extra damage.

Comment: @spartacus in late game why wouldn't he want to try to get those items. They are very powerful and they are hugely useful to the whole team, for ganks, teamfights, etc. I did not mention about the courier because i think it's common sense that the support will always buy that.

Comment: @BlueTrin It's best to use fatal bonds only by casting on the enemy hero. Yes creeps will get some extra damage, but the enemy will be harassed, lose gold, experience maybe (being forced to retreat for healing or being scared to take damage again). After all it's the carry's job to do proper last hits. In case you really manage to keep them away without fatal bods, let's say you can spare it a while, but do spend ability points in them.

Comment: @Edeph Sheepstick and necronomicon are a lot more useful than having 2 golems.  You are also better off spending gold on drums and Euls.  Or if your team has high magic damage, get veil of discord instead.  Finally, shiva is a great way of setting up your upheaval.  All of this on top of constant ward is far more effective use of gold than scepter and refresher orb.

Comment: @BleuTrin fatal bonds is serious harass if you tag both a hero and a bunch of creeps with it.  If you only cast it on creeps its worthless as you'll just push your lane for no benefit.

Comment: @spartacus I agree with you, but you must understand that every item is situational especially in the late game. I told him what he could do, indeed your suggestions are good also, but none of them are required for a winning/good game. Sheepstick and necronomicon upgraded are more expensive than the Aghanim's scepter i think and they provide smaller bonuses to sustainability which i think are more important as a support rather than doing damage. But they are good suggestions though.

Comment: @Spartacus: it is true that it was pushing the lane although he only last hitted and we tried to deny. I tried to hit both heroes with bonds, but half of the time it would stick only to 1 hero with a few creeps.

Comment: @BlueTrin if you have any other questions related to the topic please ask away!

Comment: @spartacus Without Aghanims your ultimate is free gold to Diffusal Blade. Aghs after Mek is standard; Refresher not so much (no HP).

Comment: @BlueTrin is there anything we can explain further on this subject ? If not could you mark this answer as the correct one so that the question is closed ?